# Migrating SharePoint Content database from 2010 to 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-database

Source Environment:
1.) SharePoint 2010
2.) 1 site collection
3.) 8 sites in that site collection.

The requirement i have is to move the site collection along with all the data from 2010 to 2013.

Currently i am planning to migrate the content database.
I have got [this](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/02/07/back-up-content-database-from-sharepoint-2010-and-restore-it-to-sharepoint-2013.aspx) link and i am following it.

But my source server has SQL SERVER 2008 and destination server has SQL SERVER 2012.

Is this correct what i am doing or is there any better way to do this without using content database migration? Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method is called database attach method and is preferred method of migrating from SP 2010 to SP 2013. You have got correct SQL Server at destination. There should be no issues. If both source and destination web applications are claims based you are good to go. SP 2013 allows to create only claims based web applications from UI. So if source web application is windows based and destination is claims based, you will get warning during `Test-ContentDatabse` command as can be seen in the article you have provided. The remedy for this is to create the destination web application as windows based using PowerShell and convert it later to use claims if needed. I recently did one such migration. Here are my findings:

http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.com/2014/01/upgrade-from-sharepoint-2010-classic.html

http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.com/2014/01/upgrade-from-sharepoint-2010-classic.html